# Check the length of an array before of to do a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Does make sense to check if the length of the array is not equal to 0 before of to do the loop?

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
if (arr.length !== 0) {
    // do loop
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case it doesn't make sense. For a foreach, for, or while loop, the loop condition will prevent the loop executing anyway, so your check is redundant.

```
var arr = [];
for (var loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < arr.length; loopCounter++)
{
   // This loop will never be entered.
} 

foreach (var element in arr)
{
   // This loop will never be entered.
}

var loopCounter = 0;
while (loopCounter < arr.length)
{
   // This loop will never be entered.
   loopCounter++;
}
```

**However**, the only time it is important is if you are using a do...while loop. In this scenario, the loop executes, and **then** you check your loop-condition (when it is too late). It's likely that your code would have thrown an exception inside the loop in this case, as demonstrated in the following code.

```
var arr = [];
var loopCounter = 0;
do 
{ 
   someMethod(arr[loopCounter]); // This will throw an error
   loopCounter++;
} 
while(loopCounter < arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the loop. If it's of the form:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    do_something_with (arr[i]);
}
```

then, no, the `if` is superfluous, the `for` loop body will not execute in this case.

However, if you've done something like (and this seems likely given that you mention a `do` loop, although you may have actually meant "do the loop", so it's hard to say):

```
i = 0;
do {
    do_something_with (arr[i]);
    i++;
while (i < arr.length);
```

then, yes, you'll need it to avoid the problem of using `arr[0]` if no such beast exists.

But I would consider that second case (check-after) "broken" since the `while () {}` or `for () {}` variants (check-before) would be more natural in that case.

Answer (score 1):

No, the check is unnecessary. If the array has zero elements, the loop will execute zero times (assuming it is written correctly).

If the array could be `null`, then checking for that would be valid, e.g.

```
if(arr !== null)
{
    // loop
}
```